# Problem with making my menu horizentel (ul)

Tags: html, css

i have a problem with making the list horizontally, I tries putting in display: inline; and float: right; doesn't seem to work. Hope you can help, and sorry for the badly explained problem, I just started the education. Have a great day

```css
ul {
display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
    margin-left: -17px;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 350%;
}

li a {
display: inline;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #F39D2A;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:black;">

<div class="menu">
    <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">Om os</a></li>
  <li><a href="#prt">Portfojle</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt os</a></li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code to set your menu horizontal and remove color white or give background color so you can visible text properly give float property to li only.

```css
 ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 200px;
}

li {
    float: right;
}

li a {
    display: inline;
    color: #000;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

li a.active {
    color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    color: #F39D2A;
}
```

```html
 <div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">Om os</a></li>
        <li><a href="#prt">Portfojle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt os</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, I just have to style it abit :D have a good day

Comment: Don't use `float` as sometimes it created unnecessary behaviors instead try using `flex` or `grid` properties

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox like `display: flex` in `ul`.

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%
}
```

It will align ul items in horizontal.

HTML:

```
<body style="background-color:black;">

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Om os</a></li>
    <li><a href="#prt">Portfojle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Kontakt os</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%
}

li a {
display: inline;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 0 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
}

li a.active {
  color: white;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #F39D2A;
}
```

I belive this will work. If you want adjust more, you can read about flex concept here (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).